# FileStream initialization of a Json file throws System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, uwp, youtube-api

I was following one of the Youtube API's samples provided by *Google*, but so far without much success.
This particular API requires authorized access (OAuth 2.0), and therefore I had to get the `secrets` JSON file from the Google API Console, holding the required information for the `OAuth2` operation.

I have imported the JSON file onto my UWP project, but whenever I try to set a stream to it I stumble across a *System.NotSupportedException*.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("ms-appx:///client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to 
        // authenticated user's account.
        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube },
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
        );
}
```

I have set the *BuildAction* of the JSON file to *Content* and the *Copy to Output Directory* to *Copy if newer* but also *Copy always*, but without any success.

Any ideas?

Ps: The file is at the root of the package location and therefore I have used the `ms-appx` URI scheme for simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have imported the Json file onto my UWP project

If you want to get the file from the root of your project. You could use `Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync` method to get the file. Then, you could get its file stream like the following:

```
StorageFile file = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("client_secrets.json");
using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
{
    //TODO:
}
```

Please note that if you put this json file in your project directory, this file is read-only. If you want to read and write it, you could copy it to the Application Data store. For example: [LocalFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalFolder).

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the exception you are getting is that you are using the UWP specific URI `ms-appx:///` in the classic `System.IO.FileStream` API, which doesn't understand it.

You have two options to access the file:

### **`System.IO`**

Using the classic `System.IO` types, you need to use actual filesystem paths to access the file:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(
         Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path,
         "client_secrets.json");
using (var stream = new FileStream(
      filePath, 
      FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
   ...
}
```

### `StorageFile`

You can use the `StorageFile` API, which is UWP specific and supports `ms-appx:///`. You can access the file either using `StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` method or via `InstalledLocation` `StorageFolder` as @XavierXie suggests.

The advantage of the `StorageFile` API is that it is asynchronous (non-blocking) and the recommended one in UWP, while the `System.IO` one is more universal and is actually more performant.